# Having trouble referencing foreign keys in sqlfiddle

Tags: sqlfiddle

I'm very new to coding and am having loads of trouble figuring out my 2 current problems. For the first one, I have created a table called "sales" that has a primary key, donutorder, but the table also has a foreign key customerid. I have tried writing the code but I keep getting errors in SQLFIDDLE. The second one is similar but donutorder and donutid are both primary and foreign keys in the "orderline" table. I don't know how to write the code because of the 2 foreign keys. Can any one help? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear you're having the same problem. I'm working on the same project.
After problems with the first table and the CustomerID foreign key, I omitted the foreign key and continued creating the other tables. It's interesting that I successfully completed another table with 2 foreign keys and it was fine. I have Googled everything related, including indexes (which I think may be part of the problem).
If you create all of your tables without the CustomerID foreign key reference, they will be successful. The problem shows up after the inserts and when retrieving table results. The Customer ID comes up "NULL". (At least it did on mine.)
I'm tempted to try one more time omitting the CustomerID foreign key and try to recoup with a JOIN query.
If you have any brilliant ideas, I hope you will reply.
PS About your second question--You have to put the (DonutOrderID,DonutID) as PRIMARY KEY; then 2 "Foriegn Key" lines-- one for DonutOrderID and another for DonutID with 'REFERENCES' to the associated table and field.
TH